# Unable to Undo Hijack with IBM Clear Case Eclipse Plugin 7.6.2 and Clear Case 8.0.0.6

Tags: eclipse, plugins, clearcase

i have a problem, that the Team->Undo Hijack function doesn't work with the IBM Clear Case Eclipse Plugin 7.6.2 and Clear Case 8.0.0.6. The icon of the file changes to normal, but the file is still hijacked. In the Clear Case Explorer, the file is still marked as hijacked, it's possible to undo hijack the file with the Clear Case Explorer. With the last Clear Case Version 7.x, the function worked perfectly.

Did anybody know this problem?

Thanks and Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The first check you need to do is a cleartool ls in the parent folder of the hijacked file.

That will confirm its status (hijacked, even after the "Undo Hijacked")

Then, I would recommend closing as many apps, and all files within your Eclipse workspace, before attempting again the "Undo Hijacked".
It is possible that Eclipse keeps an handle on the resource (file) you attempt to "undo hijack".

Comment: sorry for asking, but how to check that cleartool is in an parent folder of the hijacked file? Closing apps and files in eclipse helped not to go on in this problem.

Comment: @Thorgas you can check the properties of that file to see where it is, and go there through command line (closing Eclipse), and do a `cleartool update -overwrite`: But if you are talking about a web view used with ClearTeam Explorer 8.x, then you wouldn't have access to cleartool.